# Use of wildcards to replace

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I have a text and I need to change every number like NN.NN to NN.NN00. Ex. 23.43 to 23.4300
How can I do that using word

Answer (score 2):

`([0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2})` → `\100`

- `[0-9]` – any number
- `{2}` – two matches in a row
- `(` and `)` – create a group
- `\1` – insert the 1st group
- `00` – insert two zeros

For more information, see [Word](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm) [wildcard](http://home.utad.pt/~leonelm/iet/wildcards.html) [reference](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm).